# Does my processor support PAE?

Tags: windows-7, memory, 64-bit, cpu-architecture, pae

I currently have the following system specifications:

Windows 7 64-Bit

Athlon 64 X2 (W) 4600+ 2.4 GHz

8GB of RAM

500 GB HD

I'm planning on installing Xubuntu as a dual partition along side my current windows installation. On the [official Xubuntu page](http://xubuntu.org/getxubuntu/requirements/) it says:

> Your processor needs to support PAE in order to run Xubuntu.

From the microsoft website:

> PAE gives 32-bit processors the ability to use more than 4 GB of
>   physical memory on capable versions of Windows, and is a prerequisite
>   for NX.

Just for clarification seeing as I have 8GB of RAM and running Windows 7 64-Bit, PAE shouldn't be an issue, correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every 64-bit x86 CPU supports PAE. There is no 64-bit x86 without NX and there is no NX without PAE.

Comment: So, I don't need to worry, correct? I can properly install Xubuntu without worry about my CPU/PAE capability?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly right.

Comment: @iluvlinux  All 64-bit processors are x86 processors.  Its literally not possible, for a processor to support the 64-bit extension, and not support PAE.

Comment: @Ramhound: Except the 64-bit processors that are ARM64, the ones that are SPARC64, the ones that are System z, the ones that are PowerPC...

Comment: Question is about x86 processors my all statement are limited to x86 obviously, I literally limited that comment to x86 why mention ARM at all?

Comment: @Ramhound Then you're just repeating the first sentence of the answer but in a way that makes it technically incorrect.

Comment: Sure; your are right.